# Scipy.Curve fit struggling with exponential function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to fit a curve of the equation:

```
y = ( (np.exp(-k2*(t+A))) - ((k1/v)*Co) )/ -k2

where  A = (-np.log((k1/v)*Co))/k2
```

given to me by a supervisor to a dataset that looks like a rough exponential that flattens to a straight horizontal line at its top. When I fit the equation i am receiving only a straight line from the curve fit and a corresponding Warning:

```
<ipython-input-24-7e57039f2862>:36: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
 return ( (np.exp(-k2*(t+A))) - ((k1/v)*Co) )/ -k2
```

the code I am using looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

xData_forfit = [1.07683e+13, 1.16162e+13, 1.24611e+13, 1.31921e+13, 1.40400e+13, 2.65830e+13,
 2.79396e+13, 2.86676e+13, 2.95155e+13, 3.03605e+13, 3.12055e+13, 3.20534e+13,
 3.27814e+13, 3.36293e+13, 3.44772e+13, 3.53251e+13, 3.61730e+13, 3.77459e+13,
 3.85909e+13, 3.94388e+13, 4.02838e+13, 4.11317e+13, 4.19767e+13, 4.27076e+13,
 5.52477e+13, 5.64143e+13, 5.72622e+13, 5.81071e+13, 5.89550e+13, 5.98000e+13,
 6.05280e+13, 6.13759e+13, 6.22209e+13, 6.30658e+13, 6.39137e+13, 6.46418e+13,
 6.55101e+13, 6.63551e+13, 6.72030e+13, 6.80480e+13, 6.88929e+13, 6.97408e+13,
 7.04688e+13, 7.13167e+13, 7.21617e+13, 8.50497e+13, 8.58947e+13, 8.67426e+13,
 8.75876e+13, 8.83185e+13, 9.00114e+13, 9.08563e+13, 9.17013e+13]
yData_forfit = [1375.409524, 1378.095238, 1412.552381, 1382.904762, 1495.2, 1352.4,
 1907.971429, 1953.52381,  1857.352381, 1873.990476, 1925.114286, 1957.085714,
 2030.52381,  1989.8,      2042.733333, 2060.095238, 2134.361905, 2200.742857,
 2342.72381,  2456.047619, 2604.542857, 2707.971429 ,2759.87619,  2880.52381,
 3009.590476, 3118.771429, 3051.52381,  3019.771429, 3003.561905, 3083.0,
 3082.885714, 2799.866667, 3012.419048, 3013.266667, 3106.714286, 3090.47619,
 3216.638095, 3108.447619, 3199.304762, 3154.257143, 3112.419048, 3284.066667,
 3185.942857, 3157.380952, 3158.47619,  3464.257143, 3434.67619,  3291.457143,
 2851.371429, 3251.904762, 3056.152381, 3455.07619,  3386.942857]

def fnct_to_opt(t, k2, k1):
    #EXPERIMENTAL CONSTANTS
    v = 105
    Co = 1500

    A = (-np.log((k1/v)*Co))/k2
    return ( (np.exp(-k2*(t+A))) - ((k1/v)*Co) )/ -k2


initial_k2k1 = [100, 1*10**-3]
constants = curve_fit(fnct_to_opt, xData_forfit, yData_forfit, p0=initial_k2k1)
k2_fit = constants[0][0]
k1_fit = constants[0][1]


fit = []
for i in xData_forfit:
    fit.append(fnct_to_opt(i,k2_fit,k1_fit))


plt.plot(xData_forfit, yData_forfit, 'or', ms='2')
plt.plot(xData_forfit, fit)
```

this is giving me this plot as a result:
[image]

As far as i can tell, the code isn't producing a useful output due to a too large value for the np.exp term, but i don't know how to go about diagnosing where this overflow is coming from or how to fix the issue. any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.

Comment: Your posted code fails to run due to several undefined symbols.

Comment: my bad, added in the dataset so it'll run right through now. i have no idea how to go about diagnosing where exactly the overflow is happening as its buried somewhere in the opaque curve_fit.

Comment: Do you have a particular context? like industry or domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow is happening exactly where the error message tells you: in the `return` expression of `fnct_to_opt`.  I asked you to print the offending values just before the error point; this would show you the problem.

At the point of error, the values in `A` are in the range e+13 to e+14.  `t` is insignificant; `k2` is a bit under -10000.0

Thus, the values in your argument to `np.exp` are well out of the domain that the function can handle.  Just add a line to you function and watch the results:

```
def fnct_to_opt(t, k2, k1):
    #EXPERIMENTAL CONSTANTS
    v = 105
    Co = 1500

    A = (-np.log((k1/v)*Co))/k2
    print("TRACE", "\nk2", k2, "\nt", t, "\nA", A, "\nother", k1, v, Co)
    return ( (np.exp(-k2*(t+A))) - ((k1/v)*Co) )/ -k2
```

Comment: I see what you meant about printing now. I'll have to look into the equation itself i think - i assume that with this overflow i'm not going to get anywhere with it. Perhaps its a theory error. Thanks for the help

Comment: Right.  I suspect there's an error in an equation somewhere.  The quantities you're generating with e^(10^15) are a bit large for any practical purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem maybe in the optimization function, in the sense that maybe a mistake.

For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

xData_forfit = [1.07683e+13, 1.16162e+13, 1.24611e+13, 1.31921e+13, 1.40400e+13, 2.65830e+13,
 2.79396e+13, 2.86676e+13, 2.95155e+13, 3.03605e+13, 3.12055e+13, 3.20534e+13,
 3.27814e+13, 3.36293e+13, 3.44772e+13, 3.53251e+13, 3.61730e+13, 3.77459e+13,
 3.85909e+13, 3.94388e+13, 4.02838e+13, 4.11317e+13, 4.19767e+13, 4.27076e+13,
 5.52477e+13, 5.64143e+13, 5.72622e+13, 5.81071e+13, 5.89550e+13, 5.98000e+13,
 6.05280e+13, 6.13759e+13, 6.22209e+13, 6.30658e+13, 6.39137e+13, 6.46418e+13,
 6.55101e+13, 6.63551e+13, 6.72030e+13, 6.80480e+13, 6.88929e+13, 6.97408e+13,
 7.04688e+13, 7.13167e+13, 7.21617e+13, 8.50497e+13, 8.58947e+13, 8.67426e+13,
 8.75876e+13, 8.83185e+13, 9.00114e+13, 9.08563e+13, 9.17013e+13]
yData_forfit = [1375.409524, 1378.095238, 1412.552381, 1382.904762, 1495.2, 1352.4,
 1907.971429, 1953.52381,  1857.352381, 1873.990476, 1925.114286, 1957.085714,
 2030.52381,  1989.8,      2042.733333, 2060.095238, 2134.361905, 2200.742857,
 2342.72381,  2456.047619, 2604.542857, 2707.971429 ,2759.87619,  2880.52381,
 3009.590476, 3118.771429, 3051.52381,  3019.771429, 3003.561905, 3083.0,
 3082.885714, 2799.866667, 3012.419048, 3013.266667, 3106.714286, 3090.47619,
 3216.638095, 3108.447619, 3199.304762, 3154.257143, 3112.419048, 3284.066667,
 3185.942857, 3157.380952, 3158.47619,  3464.257143, 3434.67619,  3291.457143,
 2851.371429, 3251.904762, 3056.152381, 3455.07619,  3386.942857]

def fnct_to_opt(t, k2, k1):
    #EXPERIMENTAL CONSTANTS
    v = 105
    Co = 1500

    #A = (-np.log((k1/v)*Co))/k2
    #return ( (np.exp(-k2*(t+A))) - ((k1/v)*Co) )/ -k2
    #A = (np.log((k1/v)*Co))/k2
    return k2/np.log(t) + k1


initial_k2k1 = [10, 1]
constants = curve_fit(fnct_to_opt, xData_forfit, yData_forfit, p0=initial_k2k1)
k2_fit = constants[0][0]
k1_fit = constants[0][1]
#v_fit = constants[0][2]
#Co_fit = constants[0][3]

fit = []
for i in xData_forfit:
    fit.append(fnct_to_opt(i,k2_fit,k1_fit))


plt.plot(xData_forfit, yData_forfit, 'or', ms='2')
plt.plot(xData_forfit, fit)
```

So I place a function simpler but with some clearer intuition behind. For instance in the original I do not think that with those signs and exponential the shape is going to be achieve at all. However looks to me that the exponential is misplaced so I change it for log. Add a constant and a scale parameter. I would suggest to check carefully the original function. Probably there is and issue with the derivation. I do not think is a computational problem.

[image]

This is something closer to what could be expected.

Comment: thanks, i think it must be a misconseption in the equation i'm trying to fit.